# Elixir call Axis2 Java SOAP Web Service with detergentex and detergent

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, erlang, elixir

From Elixir, I am trying to call a SOAP Web Service with [detergentex](https://github.com/r-icarus/detergentex), which is a wrapper around the Erlang library [detergent](https://github.com/devinus/detergent).

I can call the SOAP Web Service in the example on the detergent home page with no problems: http://www.webservicex.net/convertVolume.asmx?WSDL

Parameters:

```
wsdl_url = "http://www.webservicex.net/convertVolume.asmx?WSDL"
action = "ChangeVolumeUnit"
parameters = ["100","dry","centiliter"]
```

However when trying to call an Axis2 Java SOAP Web Service I am having some problems. Example: http://www.thomas-bayer.com/axis2/services/BLZService?wsdl

When calling "getBank" in the following way

```
wsdl_url = "http://www.thomas-bayer.com/axis2/services/BLZService?wsdl"
action = "getBank"
parameters = ["abc"]
wsdl = Detergentex.init_model(wsdl_url)
res = Detergentex.call(wsdl, action, parameters)
```

I get the following error message:

```
{:error, 'Struct doesn\'t match model: recordtype not expected: p:getBank'}
```

with the following stack trace

```
    src/erlsom_write.erl:357: :erlsom_write.findAlternative/4
    src/erlsom_write.erl:258: :erlsom_write.processSubType/5
    src/erlsom_write.erl:241: :erlsom_write.processElementValues/7
    src/erlsom_write.erl:132: :erlsom_write.struct2xml/6
    src/erlsom_write.erl:323: :erlsom_write.processAlternativeValue/8
    src/erlsom_write.erl:241: :erlsom_write.processElementValues/7
    src/erlsom_write.erl:116: :erlsom_write.struct2xml/6
    src/erlsom_write.erl:323: :erlsom_write.processAlternativeValue/8
    src/erlsom_write.erl:241: :erlsom_write.processElementValues/7
    src/erlsom_write.erl:45: :erlsom_write.write/2
    src/detergent.erl:211: :detergent.call_attach/8
```

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Seems this is probably probably a known issue with `erlsom` parsing: https://github.com/r-icarus/detergentex/issues/7

Comment: I'm grasping at straws, but does changing: `action = "getBank"` to `action = "tns:getBank"` help?

Comment: No, it doesn't help to remove the `tns:` in `action`. An error is returned: `{:error, 'operation not found'}`

Answer (score 1):

According to the implementation a prefix is added on the `init_model`.

```
def init_model(wsdl_url, prefix \\ 'p') do
   Detergentex.Client.init_model(wsdl_url, prefix)
end
```

I would suggest to add an empty prefix.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Though, I tried changing my code from `wsdl = Detergentex.init_model(wsdl_url)` to `wsdl = Detergentex.init_model(wsdl_url, '')`, but I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: What version of the library do you use?

Comment: I'm using detergentex version 0.0.7 (newest version on hex as of today)